# Can a PDF handle html codes?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, adobe, acrobat

I have a PDF and the textbox fields are being filled automatically, unfortunately what's supposed to be a multiline textbox FULLADDRESS has turned into a single line of text with `<br>` codes embedded in it.

Is there any way I can have the PDF handle the `<br>` codes by using any settings on the text box fields? Or am I stuck with `<br>` codes?

Thanks.

Edit: Can this be done with formatting javascript editor? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for new lines in PDF multiline fields is `\r` (or `\n`).

You'd have to convert your HTML tags to these codes.

OR, if you activate the richText property of the field, you'd have to create an array of span Objects wich will then become the `richValue` property. But even there, you will have to use correct new line codes.